# virsh reverting changes to domain tag

Tags: xml, qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

My ultimate goal is to add the qemu:commandline tag to my vm's xml file, but to do that I need to change

`<domain type="qemu">`

to

`<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="qemu">`

However, whenever I make this change (whether its in virsh edit or virt-manager, it gets reverted back to the original tag. Editing the xml file dirfectly doesnt reflect any of the changes I make.

Heres the full xml file: https://pastebin.com/2dqzVfgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virsh does that in case the qemu namespace is not used.
So simply add your qemu:commandline entries too.